# Multiprocessing error: function not defined

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

The following returns "NameError: name 'times_2' is not defined", and I can't figure out why:

```
def pass_data(data): return times_2(data)

def times_2(data): return data*2

import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.pool = Pool()
pool.ncpus = 2
res = pool.map(pass_data, range(5))
print(res)
```

What I'm actually trying to do is apply a function to a pandas dataframe. However, because I can't use a lambda function to do this:

```
pool.map(lambda x: x.apply(get_weather, axis=1), df_split)
```

instead I have this with the following helper methods, but it throws a "NameError: name 'get_weather' is not defined":

```
def get_weather(df):
    *do stuff*
    return weather_df

def pass_dataframe(df):
    return df.apply(get_weather, axis=1)

results = pool.map(pass_dataframe, df_split)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Pool like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def pass_data(data): return times_2(data)

def times_2(data): return data*2

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    res = pool.map(pass_data, range(5))
    print(res)
```

On Windows:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def pass_data(data): return times_2(data)

def times_2(data): return data*2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        res = pool.map(pass_data, range(5))
        print(res)
```

See docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming

Comment: That never returns; I have to restart the python kernel to break out of it.

Comment: Maybe the dataframe is too big so your computer is running out of memory. You can verify if the process is running by executing "htop" on your command line. All of your cores should be working 100%.

The latter code returns [0, 2, 4, 6, 8] to me.

Comment: The code you provided, when I copy/paste it into Spyder, never returns. I'm using Python 3.6.5 (Anaconda distribution) on Windows 10.

Comment: oh I see, on windows you have to put with Pool(...)... inside an if __name__ == '__main__'. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Got it, thank you! One more question: my program is slowing down with >1 process! It shouldn't be a synchronization issue, as there's no single object that each process is trying to share access to write to. There is an object that is shared between each process to *read* from: I have a dict of 134 dataframes that contains weather data, with each dataframe in the dict being a different airport. The code I'm trying to multiprocess takes a list of flights, and for each origin and destination airport, looks up the weather and returns it to a dataframe. That should be easy to multiprocess, right?

Comment: I think there should be a load balance issue, maybe some process is slowing down because some of the dataframe is much bigger than others. So the processing time is theoretically almost the same as the 1 core process. Besides, the parallel processing consumes generally more time for single processes because before parallelizing objects need to be serialized and some stuff more. So in conclusion, if there is not a good load balance, the parallel process will take more time than the single thread process.

Comment: I ended up writing 7 different .py files, each one working on a different chunk of the dataframe, then running 7 different instances of the python shell, each one running a different .py file. A little brute force, but it worked.